# How do i prevent my player from walking through mesh collider

Tags: collision-detection, movement, collider, clipping, meshcollider

I have a character being moved using rigidbody.moveposition and I have an floating lowpoly island with a mesh collider. When my player walks into a steep slope or a wall, it passes right through. I assume this is because the mesh collider isn't thick enough but there must be a pretty simple fix. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Here's the code for the movement of my character.

```
private void Movement()
{
    if (AnimController.GetInteger("AnimPar") != 3)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            walkSpeed = initialWalkSpeed * 2;
        }
        else
        {
            walkSpeed = initialWalkSpeed;
        }


        if ((Forward && Right) || (Forward && Left) || (Backward && Right) || (Backward && Left))
        {
            walkSpeed *= .7f;
        }

        if (Forward)
        {
            Delta += transform.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Backward)
        {
            Delta -= transform.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Right)
        {
            Delta += transform.right * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Left)
        {
            Delta -= transform.right * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        }



        rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(Delta.x, transform.position.y, Delta.z));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `AddForce` instead of `SetPosition` on your rigid body. Setting the position will place the body at the new position, but adding a force will cause the body to move through the simulation steps. Make sure you use continuous collision detection.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home but wouldn't that make the movement much less responsive?

Comment: You can use a large force but you should adapt it to limit the speed of the character.

Comment: And how would you do that? Lower the force as the velocity increases?

Comment: Would it be possible to send an example?

Comment: Yes, you check the velocity and if it is low, use more force and if it is high use less force. What engine and language are you using?

Comment: I use c# in unity but I've changed my code to change the velocity directly however the changing of directions is still very wonky.

Comment: You might want to add a high friction force or something to stop you when you release a key. Are you fixed to the terrain any better?

Comment: Yes my character doesn’t clip through the collider anymore my problem now is that I can’t figure out how to stop velocity in only one direction since I think velocity uses the world axis. The only solutions I have are stop the velocity altogether when I release a key which sadly prevents strafing and makes things feel wonky or stop velocity along an axis which doesn’t use my character’s normalized directions.